# regex to match digit word in numbers

Tags: php, regex

Here is my regex to validate the phone number. which works fine for various numbers like `1223534345` etc .

```
/(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/
```

snippet:

```
foreach ($words as $word){

    $arrwords = array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine');
    preg_match_all('/[A-za-z]+/', $text, $matches);
    $arr=$matches[0];
    foreach($arr as $v)
    {
       $text= str_replace($v,array_search($v,$arrwords),$text);
    }

    $pattern = '/(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
    $this->pushToResultSet($matches);
}
```

But I want to add exploits like this:

`1223five34345`, it should also be considered as `1223534345` and should be filtered. Is this possible ?

Comment: do you also need to validate ten and eleven and maybe zwenty?

Comment: @AndreschSerj: no, up to 0 to 9 is ok

Comment: its really hard to understand what are your test conditions. because there's also checks for `space` and `+`. If you had written the above `regex` yourself then I'll suggest you to try `http://regex101.com/` and test for your other test cases

Comment: @MohammadFaisal: yes, as I am validing phone numbers, I am considering `+` and space too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation :

Map all those words as shown in the `$arrwords` , now do a `preg_match_all()` to check for all the occurrences of the words. Grab them in array. Now loop that array and check if that value exists in the `$arrwords` array , if found map the key to the string.

```
<?php
$arrwords = array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine');
$str='I won total five prize';
preg_match_all('/[A-za-z]+/', $str, $matches);
$arr=$matches[0];
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    $v = strtolower($v); //<--- Fail safe !!
    if(in_array($v,$arrwords))
    {
    $str = str_replace($v,array_search($v,$arrwords),$str);
    }
}
echo $str; //I won total 5 prize
```

You can now validate this `$str` with your regular expression.

Comment: I dont want to remove it. I want it to consider but as a digit

Comment: thanks a lot dude. But I get text from user, from that I consider number to filter them out. If text is like this `I won total five prize` then will it replace this `five` also to `5`?

Comment: @Programming_crazy, Just add an `in_array()` check , I have modified my answer.

Comment: it meant it should convert `word digit` to `numeric digid` only if it is inside any number. I won five prizes is sentence. `five` is not inside any number so we dont need to convert it. I filter phone numbers. So in phone number if user enters this exploit then I need to catch it